# How to control mariadb server using systemctl?

Tags: 16.04, systemd, mariadb

Installed MariaDB via

```
apt install mariadb-server
```

Wanted to start it, but it seems that
mariadb-server.service is not installed:

```
systemctl enable mariadb
systemctl enable mariadb-server
```

they both fail.

```
dpkg -L mariadb-server-10.0 | grep service
```

shows nothing.
But various tutorials on the web instruct to issue these commands.

How to install *.service* files and why they are absent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `mariadb-server` is a metapackage, so it is empty & it is created only for dependencies declarations

  ```
  ~$ apt-cache search "mariadb-server*"
  auth2db - Powerful and eye-candy IDS logger, log viewer and alert generator
  mariadb-server - MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
  mariadb-server-10.0 - MariaDB database server binaries
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 - MariaDB database core server files

  ~$ apt-cache depends mariadb-server
  mariadb-server
    Depends: mariadb-server-10.0

  ~$ apt-cache -i depends mariadb-server-10.0 
  mariadb-server-10.0
    PreDepends: adduser
    PreDepends: debconf
    PreDepends: mariadb-common
    Depends: libdbi-perl
    Depends: lsb-base
    Depends: mariadb-client-10.0
    Depends: mariadb-server-core-10.0
    Depends: passwd
      passwd:i386
    Depends: perl
    Depends: psmisc
      psmisc:i386
   |Depends: debconf
    Depends: <debconf-2.0>
      cdebconf
      debconf
    Depends: libaio1
    Depends: libc6
    Depends: libpam0g
    Depends: libstdc++6
    Depends: zlib1g
  ```
- It does not have a `systemd` entry but an `init.d` one with different name.

  [`/etc/init.d/mysql`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/mariadb-server-10.0/filelist)

  `systemd-sysv-generator` should have already generated a service file with same name, check it:

  ```
   systemctl status mysql.service
  ```